# Excel string converting

Tags: excel

How do I convert the following data in cell B4 of my excel spreadsheet: "1 day 23 hrs 11 mins" into a number that I can run a pivot table and graphs off of?

Ideally I'd like to scratch the minutes and just deal with the hours and days and have one value produced (hours).

1 Day = 8 hr workday

Thanks

CSC

Comment: Looking for a VBA solution?

Comment: If one day = 8 hrs then `23 hrs 11 mins` seems odd - I would expect the hours and minutes to not exceed 7:59....wouldn't "1 day 23 hrs 11 mins" = "3 days 7 hrs 11 mins"?

Comment: @barryhoudini: The user wants to ignore the mins...

Comment: OK Sid, I edited my suggestion....

Answer (score 3):

Here is a VBA Method. Let me know if you don't want a VBA method and I will delete it.

Place this code in a module. This code takes into considerations for all matches between `days/day` and `hrs/hr`

**Code**

```
Function ConvertToHours(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim DAr() As String, HAr() As String, strVal As String
    Dim D As Long, H As Long

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ConvertToHours = 0
    Else
        strVal = LCase(rng.Value)

        If InStr(1, strVal, "days", vbTextCompare) Then
            DAr = Split(strVal, "days")
            D = Val(Trim(DAr(0)))

            If InStr(1, strVal, "hrs", vbTextCompare) Then
                HAr = Split(DAr(1), "hrs")
                H = Val(Trim(HAr(0)))
            ElseIf InStr(1, strVal, "hr", vbTextCompare) Then
                HAr = Split(DAr(1), "hr")
                H = Val(Trim(HAr(0)))
            End If
        ElseIf InStr(1, strVal, "day", vbTextCompare) Then
            DAr = Split(strVal, "day")
            D = Val(Trim(DAr(0)))

            If InStr(1, strVal, "hrs", vbTextCompare) Then
                HAr = Split(DAr(1), "hrs")
                H = Val(Trim(HAr(0)))
            ElseIf InStr(1, strVal, "hr", vbTextCompare) Then
                HAr = Split(DAr(1), "hr")
                H = Val(Trim(HAr(0)))
            End If
        End If

        ConvertToHours = (D * 8) + H
    End If
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula to get hours as a decimal

`=SUM(MID(0&A1,FIND({"d","h","m"},A1)-2,2)*{480,60,1})/60`

assumes that days, hrs and mins will all be present - works for up to 99 days

If you don't care about the minutes then you can use just

`=SUM(MID(0&A1,FIND({"d","h"},A1)-2,2)*{8,1})`

Comment: + 1 You never cease to surprise me :)

Answer (score 0):

try the WORKDAY function. If you click the cell, and type in =WORKDAY(8,1), it should tell you the information you need. Hope it helps!